# Change AWS ElasticBeanstalk security group used for deployment from Visual Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visual-studio-2019, publish

I had an ElasticBeanstalk environment set up on AWS, using Windows hosting for my ASP.Net site. For various reasons I decided to build a new environment to replace that one. After updating DNS to direct to the new environment and verifying that everything worked I terminated the old environment. Termination failed but the new environment continued to work fine. Eventually I figured out that the termination failed because that old environment had created a security group that was referenced by my new environment. I removed that reference and terminated the old environment. The new environment continued to function normally.

Now I'm trying to publish an update using the AWS extensions for Visual Studio 2019. It fails with this error.

`Failed Environment update activity. Reason: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxx-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-XXXXXXXXXXX' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SecurityGroups'): The security group 'awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxx-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-XXXXXXXXXXX' does not exist`

So clearly my local extension has a reference to that old security group and now I can't deploy but I don't know where that option is set.

How do I update my local configuration for AWS publishing? Is there a config file tucked around somewhere that tells the tooling how to publish this site? The AWS Explorer continues to work normally as far as I can tell. Does it hold that info? Should I remove and recreate my credentials in the AWS Explorer in Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you run across this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-add-security-group/

Comment: I didn't end up using that technique but I did kinda solve the problem. Looking at that article I realized I can create a new security group with whatever name I want so I just used the UI to create a security group with the same name as the old group. It has no inbound or outbound rules set up but it satisifies AWS during the deploy. I'd rather find out how to truly fix it by updating the name wherever Visual Studio is keeping it but at least I can deploy again.